# Customizing Powerleve10k prompt

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just added the Powerlevel10k theme to my zsh and i'm trying to configure certain parts.

It currently looks like this:

[image]

The `~/.p10k.zsh` has a lot of configurations done and I've been trying to change certain things but i'm not there yet.

I don't want to print the whole path on the left prompt, just the directory. Also, not sure what those numbers indicate in the git section. And the right prompt is displaying my ruby version, although I haven't used Ruby in ages and want to change it to a different setting.

I've tried adding a `PS1=...` to `.zshrc` but it seems to be overriden by the P10K config file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: These are actually 3 questions (prompt segments to change). Can you post an [example] of what you tried already? Please also describe wanted change of _version segment_.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

#### Display only the last directory segment

1. Open `~/.p10k.zsh`.
2. Search for `POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_STRATEGY`.
3. Change the value of this parameter to `truncate_to_last`.

Alternatively, change the value of `POWERLEVEL9K_DIR_MAX_LENGTH` to `1`. This will maximally shorten current directory while keeping the transformation reversible. You can restore the original directory by copy-pasting the shortened directory to the command line and pressing `TAB`.

#### Ruby version

Powerlevel10k has several prompt segments that can display Ruby version. By default only those are enabled that display Ruby version when it has been manually overridden by some tool (e.g., `rbenv` or `asdf`).

To remove Ruby version from prompt:

1. Open `~/.p10k.zsh`.
2. Search for `POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_SEGMENTS`.
3. Remove or comment out the following elements: `rbenv`, `rvm` and `asdf`.

Alternatively (and perhaps preferably), find out which tool is overriding Ruby version for you and remove the override if you no longer need it.

Comment: yeah this save my time... but can you please tell me how to make last directory i mean current directory in bold ? While i shorten the dir path the current directory goes to regular font not in bold anymore. How to fix it ?

Comment: @ami_PBJ `POWERLEVEL9K_PATH_HIGHLIGHT_BOLD=true`

Answer (score 12):

#### shorten dir segment to show only deepest directory

To show only last *n significant* path segments, you can set following in your config `.zshrc`, e.g n=1 means show only last folder in present working directory:

```
POWERLEVEL9K_SHORTEN_DIR_LENGTH=1
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49027654

#### explain Git symbols

The *question/exclamation mark* in Git segment (vcs segment, next to path) means the *number of files* **untracked** (`?`) and **unstaged** (`!`). For detailed description see [What do different symbols in Git status mean?](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k/blob/master/README.md#what-do-different-symbols-in-git-status-mean)

#### change version segment

You can change the version segment (on the right of prompt) to reflect another tool. For example to replace shown *ruby version* by *python version*  replace the element within *right promt elements* in your config `.zshrc`:

```
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(rbenv)
```

by

```
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(pyenv)
```

Comment: whoever you are, after 30 mins of wasting my time on trying various things, finally your solution is what helped me.